# Concerning the benefits of currying in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning functional programming and came across the term currying. Moreover, I got that it allows us to turn a function having more than one parameter into functions having one parameter at a time. But, I really cannot get why we need to use it and what advantage we get from it. Also, if you look at the code below, we are running curriedMultiply5() several times, is it true that the benefit of currying is that it helps us run code only once and reuse its output several times, that is, currying helps us achieve efficiency. The question is why we need to use currying Is it because of code efficiency that it helps us to achieve?:

```
const curriedMultiply= (a) => (b) => a*b;
const curriedMultiply5= curriedMultiply(5);

curriedMultiply5(4);
curriedMultiply5(4);
curriedMultiply5(4);
```

Comment: please add your question.

Comment: Currying advantage is that you can use specific parts of multiple functions. This is practical if you already have several existing functions and need to use only certain ones.

Comment: @zer00ne, hey thank you for your kind reply, you mean thanks to currying we divide function with several parameters and divide it into several functions each having one parameter. And then we can take one function out of several and use. Is that correct?

Comment: According to my browser's js engine (some version of v8) there is no efficiency increase in, at the very least, that example. https://jsperf.com/curried-vs-not-curried.

Comment: @Mason, ok then why do we need to use currying?

Comment: @zer00ne, please I really need your help:(

Comment: @Dickens can't help you there. your question is the first I've heard of "currying" haha

Comment: Please kind people help

Comment: @Dickens yeah basically you pick the functions you want, pass their results through a single function. In functional programming its encouraged practice to write several simple functions and to curry them into spefic uses.

Comment: BTW this site requires broken code from the OP (Original Post) so that we the answerers can help fix it.

Comment: @zer00ne, I was just watching JS tutorial and author said that currying helps us to avoid running the same function several times but run it once and put its result into variable to reuse. For example, if you look at the above code, we are trying to execute curriedMultiply5 three times but that function is run only once. Is it logical or nonsense?

Comment: Using variables is one way, you can also pass the actual functions into another function as well. Google  *"JavaScript Functional Programming"*.

Answer (score 0):

As example, you could think of a function which takes a parameter, like a value added tax (VAT) and return a function which has a single parameter for a value for calculating a price with VAT.

This function is ready to use as callback only by taking a single parameter to set the VAT and get an array of prices with VAT.

```js
const addVAT = vat => price => price + price * vat;

var vat = 0.2,
    pricesWithoutVAT = [0.2, 1.11, 30.99],
    pricesWithVAT = pricesWithoutVAT.map(addVAT(vat));

console.log(pricesWithVAT);
```